# execCommand for SaveAs not working in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: internet-explorer, execcommand

Below is function which I am using to save csv file using `execCommand`

```
function opensave() {

   var w = window.open('about:blank', '_blank');

   w.document.write(csvText);

   w.document.close();

   var success = w.document.execCommand('SaveAs',  true, 'test.csv');

   w.close();
}
```

I am not able to see **SaveAs** dialog in **IE 9**

If I remove `true` from

```
w.document.execCommand('SaveAs',  true, 'test.csv');
```

**SaveAs** dialog opens, but I am seeing filename as `untitled` in SaveAs dialog.

How do I get filename as `test.csv` instead of `untitled` in `SaveAs` dialog  ?

Thanks